# Smallest size of GGplot2 geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot made with GGplot2. Now when i want to change the size of my text points within the plot, the size of the text does not change. I use the following line of code:

```
ggplot(data = out, aes(x = V2, y = V1)) +
    ****geom_text(data = out[!is.na(out$V1),], aes(label = labels, alpha=0.3, size=0.1))**** +
    facet_grid(id1 ~ id2,scales="fixed")+
    geom_text(data=df.text,aes(pos,pos,label=id1)) + geom_abline( slope=1 ) + 
    ggtitle("Corralation between measured & calculated affinities") +
    ylab("") + xlab("") + theme(panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
}
```

I put ** between start and end of the line of interest fat. I know that size is the right parameter to change, but why isn't my text changing when for instance making size=0.01.

Comment: Move the size argument outside of the aes brackets? I.e. make that line `geom_text(data = out[!is.na(out$V1),], aes(label = labels, alpha=0.3), size=0.1)+`. Then changing size should alter text size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Adam Kimberley, the size parameter should be moved outside of the 2nd brackets like this `geom_text(data = out[!is.na(out$V1),], aes(label = labels), size=0.1, alpha=0.3)`
Than size of the text alters.

Comment: For forming good habits, you should also move the `alpha` outside of `aes()`. Only put things inside `aes()` that map to the data. Something that's constant for a given `geom` should be specified outside of `aes()`.